# deletion of tmp directory content on RHEL

Tags: redhat, tmp

we have installed Web logic server 10.3.6 in RHEL 5.8.There also a "tmp" folder inside "domains/servers/tmp" folder..this is the path of tmp folder in my case.Now My query is "Is it Mandatory to delete files from tmp folder manually or the The Server will take care of this action..please let me.If we have no action taken for "tmp deletion is there any Impact on Application server"?

Answer (score 1):

[The manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/domain_config/config_files.html) has the following to say::

> **`servers/server-name/tmp`**
>
> This directory holds temporary directories and files that are created
>   while a server instance is running. For example, a JMS paging
>   directory is automatically created here unless another location is
>   specified. **Files in this directory must be left alone while the server
>   is running, but may be freely deleted when the server instance is shut
>   down.**

So not automatic clean-up, but the tmp directory will be (re-) created when not present on start-up. Possibly also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16732610/2952385) on SO.